# Battery indicator icon in Astra Linux

Tags: linux

I have installed Astra Linux Common Edition on my laptop, but there isn't a battery indicator. I am able to find out this information in the application **fly-admin-power**, but I would like to see this in the corner of the desktop. This icon appears only when the application **fly-admin-power** starts and disappears afterwards. How to set up battery indicator icon?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by launch application **qbat** (Монитор батареи питания).

Comment: Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.